# Jquery not working on dialog box from list view

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, sharepoint-addin, custom-javascript

I am attempting to use some DOM manipulation to change list column names on a list Display view.

However when I use Jquery to create the array I get a null value.  My test site has the Dialogs setting at No on the list while the Production site has it set to Yes so I am guessing this is what is causing the issue with `$('.ms-standardheader');` returning a null value on the production site when I try it in the console window.

On the test site this works without fail, I get my array, and I can do what I need to do.

When I change the Production site to No dialog and run `$('.ms-standardheader')` in the console I get my array.  Perfect!  Just what I want.

So, I am pretty sure I know what the issue is but how do I get around the dialog box so my `$('.ms-standardheader');` returns the array it is supposed to return?

Is this some issue related to focus or something?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any update ? Have you tried to add Jquery in DispForm.aspx using SharePoint Designer as suggested in answer below  and did it work ?

Comment: I guess I should have asked the question differently.  I did not add jquery to the DispForm as it was being loaded in the CEWP of said form.  Was trying to understand how to get past the issue of the code above failing when the form opened in a dialog box vs. full page.

Comment: No matter dialogue or Full Page, the key point is to add code into DispForm.aspx, as the field control is in dispFrom.aspx rather than AllItems.aspx. Hopefully, this will help you. In the answer, the way to inject using SharePoint Designer will get past the issue as it will add the code into DispForm directly.

Comment: When open DispForm.aspx in full page, it will redirect to the DispForm.aspx directly, so code will work. When open in dialogue, the real page is still AllItems.aspx, so adding code won't work as it's added in AllItems.aspx not DispForm.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Actually the List Display form url will like this:

http://sp/Lists/ListName/DispForm.aspx

This is not the same page as AllItems.aspx, so when launch display form in dialogue,$('.ms-standardheader') will be null as the Jquery code is added in AllItems.aspx rather than DispForm.aspx.

A workaround to inject Jquery into real DispForm.aspx is using SharePoint Designer, open the target list in SharePoint Designer and select DispForm.aspx:

[image]

Then add Jquery code under PlaceHolderMain tag:

[image]